# How do I determine the IRA contribution limits for my non-working spouse who is over 50?

Tags: united-states, ira

I am working and my spouse is not. I am under 50 and not eligible for the additional "catch-up" contribution, but she is. Am I allowed to make a spousal contribution at the catch-up rate in her account or is the limit still based on my own age?

Other relevant info:

- We file jointly.
- I have more income that the total amount I expect to contribute to both accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the [limit for the non-working spouse](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-IRA-Contribution-Limits) in $6,500 as long as the combined income is greater than the total contributions for both spouses.

> **Spousal IRAs**
>
> If you file a joint return, you and your spouse can each make IRA
>   contributions even if only one of you has taxable compensation. The
>   amount of your combined contributions can’t be more than the taxable
>   compensation reported on your joint return. It doesn’t matter which
>   spouse earned the compensation.
>
> **Examples**:
>
> Sarah, age 52, is married with no taxable compensation for 2012. She and her husband reported taxable compensation of $60,000 on their
>   2013 joint return. Sarah may contribute $6,500 to her IRA for 2013
>   ($5,500 plus an additional $1,000 contribution for age 50 and over).